# cordova's barcode scanner plugin causes config.xml error

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

I am trying to use cordova.plugin.barcodescanner to work with my app.
the plugin adds these lines to my config.xml

```
<config-file mode="merge" parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml">  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />  
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />  
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />  
</config-file>
```

when I try to build apk(debug), I get malformed config.xml error.

Then I add this  to my widget tag:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

resulting in building the app properly, but my http.get(ajax) breaks and stops working.

**Here's my full config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>  
<widget android-versionCode="24" defaultlocale="en-US" id="com.fynsis.fyncrmqrapp" version="1.0.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps">  
    <name><MY APP NAME></name>  
    <description><MY DESC></description>  
    <author email="TEST@gmail.com" href=""><MY NAME></author>  
    <content src="index.html" />  
    <access origin="*" />  
    <vs:features />  
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />  
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />  
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />  
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="4000" />  
    <preference name="windows-target-version" value="8.1" />  
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />  
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />  
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />  
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />  
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />  
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />  
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />  
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />  
    <platform name="android">  
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />  
    </platform>  
    <platform name="ios">  
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />  
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />  
    </platform>  
    <platform name="android">  
        <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />  
        <icon density="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />  
        <icon density="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />  
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />  
    </platform>  
    <platform name="ios">  
        <icon height="180" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png" width="180" />  
        <icon height="60" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />  
        <icon height="120" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120" />  
        <icon height="76" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />  
        <icon height="152" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png" width="152" />  
        <icon height="40" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />  
        <icon height="80" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png" width="80" />  
        <icon height="57" src="res/icons/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />  
        <icon height="114" src="res/icons/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />  
        <icon height="72" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />  
        <icon height="144" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />  
        <icon height="29" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />  
        <icon height="58" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png" width="58" />  
        <icon height="50" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />  
        <icon height="100" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50-2x.png" width="100" />  
    </platform>  
    <platform name="windows">  
        <icon height="150" src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" />  
        <icon height="360" src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" />  
        <icon height="30" src="res/icons/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" />  
        <icon height="310" src="res/icons/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />  
        <icon height="44" src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" width="44" />  
        <icon height="106" src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" />  
        <icon height="70" src="res/icons/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" />  
        <icon height="71" src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" width="71" />  
        <icon height="170" src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" />  
        <icon height="50" src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" />  
        <icon height="120" src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" />  
        <icon height="150" src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />  
        <icon height="360" src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" />  
    </platform>  
    <platform name="wp8">  
        <icon height="99" src="res/icons/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" width="99" />  
        <icon height="159" src="res/icons/wp8/Background.png" width="159" />  
    </platform>  
    <platform name="android">  
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" />  
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" />  
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" />  
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" />  
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />  
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />  
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />  
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />  
    </platform>  
    <platform name="ios">  
        <splash height="480" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />  
        <splash height="960" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />  
        <splash height="1024" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />  
        <splash height="2048" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" width="1536" />  
        <splash height="1136" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-568h-2x.png" width="640" />  
        <splash height="1334" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png" width="750" />  
        <splash height="2208" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png" width="1242" />  
        <splash height="1242" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />  
    </platform>  
    <platform name="windows">  
        <splash height="300" src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" width="620" />  
        <splash height="1920" src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-240.png" width="1152" />  
        <splash height="1920" src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" width="1152" />  
    </platform>  
    <platform name="wp8">  
        <splash height="1280" src="res/screens/wp8/SplashScreenImage.png" width="768" />  
    </platform>  
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />  
    <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="28" />  
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="26" />  
    <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />  
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" version="1.1.3" />  
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" version="2.4.0" />  
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-compat" version="1.1.0" />  
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" version="4.0.1" />  
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">  
        <string>This app features timesheet entries, i.e, user can punch in/out recording their date, time and location. work hours are calculated based on it. The location information is sent their own CRM systems for their manager's reference for reviewing timesheets.</string>  
    </edit-config>  
    <config-file mode="merge" parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml">  
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />  
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />  
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />  
    </config-file>  
    <engine name="android" spec="~5.1.1" />  
</widget>
```

Here's my log:

### Build Date: 2018-10-31 09:43:49 +0000

### PLUGIN OUTPUT

Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist@1" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" at "1.3.3" for android

This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android greater than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do *not* need this plugin since the whitelist will be built in.
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-device@1.1.3" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-device" at "1.1.3" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-geolocation@2.4.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-geolocation" at "2.4.0" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-compat@^1.0.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-compat" at "1.2.0" for android
Plugin "cordova-plugin-compat" already installed on android. Making it top-level.
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-splashscreen@4.0.1" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" at "4.0.1" for android
WARNING: Overriding compileSdkVersion from android-25 (default) to android-26

### WARNING: This is unsupported, please consider updating your phonegap version instead

### PROJECT PROPERTIES

This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!

This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.

To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
"ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
project structure.

To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
Project target.
target=android-26

### android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib

### COMPILE OUTPUT

Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Running command: /project/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /project/build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
at build_dwomais0s9mkq91rc7xy5fcb5.run(/project/build.gradle:137)
The JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please use TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead.
The ProjectDependency.getProjectConfiguration() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0.
ModuleDependency.getConfiguration() has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Use ModuleDependency.getTargetConfiguration() instead.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources
:CordovaLib:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug
:prepareProjectCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl
:compileDebugRenderscript
:generateDebugBuildConfig
:generateDebugResValues
:generateDebugResources
:mergeDebugResources
:processDebugManifest
:processDebugResources
:generateDebugSources
:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugSources
:mergeDebugShaders
:compileDebugShaders
:generateDebugAssets
:mergeDebugAssets
:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
:validateSigningDebug
:packageDebug
:assembleDebug
:cdvBuildDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2.007 secs
Command finished with error code 0: /project/gradlew cdvBuildDebug,-b,/project/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
Built the following apk(s): 
/project/build/outputs/apk/project-debug.apk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the lines into `<platform name="android">` tag

And i think you have to do the same (`<platform name="ios">`
) for these lines :

```
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">  
    <string>This app features timesheet entries, i.e, user can punch in/out recording their date, time and location. work hours are calculated based on it. The location information is sent their own CRM systems for their manager's reference for reviewing timesheets.</string>  
</edit-config>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Your solution worked for building the apk successfully, also, ajax is also working fine.
But now the barcode scanner isn't working anymore.
Of couse, when i try through phonegap desktop app, the whole app is working flawlessly.

Comment: Do you have any log ?

Comment: I have updated my original question and inserted log, it doesn't seem to be installing barcode scanner plugin

Comment: Thanks.. Your solution worked, also, as you pointed to log, the plugin was not properly installed, so reinstalling fixed plugin issue where as <platform name="ios" on <edit-config> tags solved other errors.

I can't thank you enough for support and patience.